# How to fix Undefined Index warnings?

Tags: php

This is the warning I am getting.

Undefined index: errormsg in /var/www/html/ies.aacrao.org/apply/begin.php on line 8

on this line of code:

```
if ($_GET['errormsg'] == "no_appid") {

$_SESSION['errormsg'] = "There was a problem with your application.  Please reenter all data.";

}
```

Hope someone can help me put.

Comment: http://us2.php.net/isset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check with `isset` like

```
if (isset($_GET['errormsg']) && $_GET['errormsg'] == 'no_appid') {
    $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "There was a problem with your application.  Please reenter all data.";
}
```

look at [php isset](https://www.php.net/isset)

Comment: Will give it a try! @Thaigo Franca

Comment: @user3594109 if it worked for you please set as correct answer.

Comment: trying to, but i get a warning saying i cant accept and asnwer in 6 minutes. I guess I will have to wait 6 minutes to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It means `$_GET['errormsg']` wasn't set. You could check for that like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['errormsg']) && $_GET['errormsg'] == "no_appid") {
}
```

Comment: @ThiagoFranca had the same answer and it looks like it worked, Thanks guys.